# Cannot git clone with system call in perl

Tags: git, perl, batch-file

I'm trying to call a git log command in perl through system an output it to a file, but I it keeps saying "not a git repository".  My code is below.  Any suggestions?

The perl snippet:

```
Readonly my $CLONE_COMMAND => 'git_clone.bat';
Readonly my $GIT_LOG_COMMAND => 'git_log_pretty';

system("$GIT_LOG_COMMAND > $GIT_REPO_XML_FILE");
```

git_clone.bat: (the repo url is passed in as %1, the name of the repo as %2)

```
@echo off
cd "c:\MyGit"
git clone "%1"
cd "c:\MyGit\%2"
```

git_log_pretty.bat:

```
git log --pretty="format:<author>%an</author>%n<date>%ai</date>%n<msg>don't care</msg>%n" --name-only
```

Comment: What's giving the error, `git_clone` or `git_log_pretty`? If it's the former, how do you call `git_clone`? If it's the latter, what's the output of `use Cwd; print getcwd(), "\n";` before the `system` call?

Comment: The git_log_pretty is the one that is causing the error.  When I print the directory, using your advice it prints "C:\MyGit\hone (hone is the repo it clones).

Answer (score 0):

Busch, do you know what Perl's current working directory is?

You can try:

```
use Cwd;
$dir = getcwd();
print $dir;
```

Make sure it's running from within your repository when you are asking for the 'git log', and try 'chdir' into there within the script if it isn't.

Comment: The working dir is set at C:\MyGit\hone (hone being the repo I cloned)